# Use crypto.js to create text form generator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create form for my user with two inputs area, the form will generate encrypt text that i can use it in javascript like user inter them in input form fields.

For example i have this html code

```
<div class='code'>john123/52544888822</div>
```

i want to make this john123/52544888822 encrypted and receive orgin text in javascript function.

HTML code:

```
<form class='form' name='form' action="" method="">
  <input class="user" type="text" name="user" value="">
  <input class="password" type="text" name="password" value=""/>
  <input class="button" type="button" value="get code"/>
</form>
<div class='code'></div>
```

Javascript code:

```
$('.form').change("input", function() {
  var form_user = $('.user').val(),
      form_password = $('.form .url').val(),
      form_button = $('.form .password');
      form_button.click(function() {
            $('.code').html('<span>[' + form_user + '][' + form_password + ']</span>');
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all get your code fixed:

```
<form class='form' name='envato-form' action="" method="">
  <input class="user" type="text" name="user" value="">
<input class="code" type="text" name="code" value="">
  <input class="password" type="text" name="password" value=""/>
  <input class="button" type="button" value="get code"/>
</form>
<div class='code'></div>
```

then javascript:

```
$('.form').change("input", function() {
  var form_user = $('.form .user').val();
  var form_code = $('.form .code').val();
  var form_password = $('.form .password').val();
  var form_button = $('.form .button');
      form_button.click(function() {
            $('.code').html('<span>' + form_user + form_code + '/' + form_password + '</span>');
      });
  });
```

then crypto.js

```
var SHA256 = require("crypto-js/sha256");
$('.code').append('<br><span>'+SHA256($('.code .span').html())+'</span>');
```

All the best!